# Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:9 mismatched input 'from' expecting SET near 'a' in update statement

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

> I tried to update table 1 , without Setting Table Properties and i've
>   got the following error " mismatched input 'from' expecting SET near
>   'a' "

```
UPDATE a from table1 a ,(SELECT  
            DISTINCT SUBS SUB,
            Min(LINE) Over(PARTITION BY CONTRACT) LINE
        FROM 
            table1 K
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT
                CUSTOMER,
                FROM,
                TO,
                CONTRACT
            FROM
                Number_Change a
            JOIN 
                CONTRACTS b  ON a.CONTRACT=b.ID
        ) CH_SUB
        ON K.CUSTOMER = CH_SUB.CUSTOMER where (SUBO = Substr(FROM,4) OR SUBO = Substr(TO,4))
    )SRC 
     set  a.LINE = SRC.LINE,  TEC_UPDATE_DTTM = Current_Timestamp 
     WHERE SUBS = SUB;
```

Comment: You have a column named `FROM` which is an SQL keyword which causes this issue so you need to escape it somehow. Not sure how to do it in this flavour of SQL but something like `'FROM'` or `[FROM]` (using the alias might also work, `a.FROM`). Try to avoid using basic SQL keywords like this as table or column names

Comment: i know that , because  i'm juste using alias to post the code here  due to confidential issue , but the probleme is not that  , the update get error due to  the join between the two tables , how can i arrange that , please